# Custom sorting in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I have a table with a column named category. the data in it is 1, 2, 3 so every row has a category.

I need sort data by category like this

1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,....

then if some category finished sorting continues like this

1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,....

I am using PostgreSQL.

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by category order by category)
```

You can specify whatever you want for the `order by`.  For instance, if you want a *random* ordering:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by category order by random())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
SELECT
   c,
   RANK () OVER ( 
      ORDER BY c 
   ) rank_number 
FROM
   ranks;
```

[image: Results:]

For more information: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID from (
select *,row_number() over ( partition by id order by id ) rn from Yourtable  
) I
order by  rn,id
```